# Changing VARCHAR to INT or MEDIUMINT?

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my database table that is currently VARCHAR datatype but has numeric values in it so I want to change the data type.  When I try to change it to MEDIUMINT, I get an error saying "#1265 - Data truncated for column 'fees' at row 1"

Any ideas how to change the data type?  I'm using phpmyadmin to do this.

Comment: What sort of numeric values?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 15,000-20,000.

Comment: Integers? Fractions? ASCII-encoded? With or without thousands separators? What? Be exact. Or, better yet, _demonstrate_, with a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure if changing to a numeric datatype helps but I am unable to search for numeric data on my website (no items will show in the search results) and I've been told be a couple of devs that my column's data type is the problem.

Comment: Well using `VARCHAR` to store numbers is certainly not right but that in itself won't automatically give you "no search results". It sounds like your devs are fobbing you off with the first thing you should fix in order to save time having to look at the actual problem. We can't help you, either, without a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just showed you an example.  Here it is again: 15,000-20,000 <== that's literally what is in a column cell.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've also spent hours working on this problem working on the code so no, I seriously doubt the devs are "fobbing" me off.  Please give me a real solution.

Comment: Eh... in what way is the string `15,000-20,000` a "numeric value"? What `MEDIUMINT` value did you expect this to be automatically converted to? If you want a real solution, give us a real question with real details. I have linked to the page on [MCVE]s three times now.

Comment: Ok...is varchar a good datatype or not for the example I just posted?

Comment: @Thomas - What is the value `'15,000-20,000'` meant to represent?  It certainly isn't an integer.  Perhaps it's a calculation, the answer to which is `-5000`, in which case store `-5000` in an `integer` column?  Perhaps it's a range of values, in which store it in two separate `integer` columns?  *(`min_val, max_val`)*  You need to provide a whole lot more information and context if you want us to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be beyond the range or may have string values in the column.

MEDIUMINT   -8388608 to 8388607

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: what do you mean?  Are you saying I am unable to change datatypes because the data in the column has characters that are incompatible with the datatype?

Comment: Yes, try to change in INT if you still facing same issue there may be a problem in your data.

Comment: There may be empty space as well. Take a backup and use `TRIM()` function to remove space then update in the same column. After try to change your data type.

Comment: OP has said the data is literally the string `"15,000-20,000"`. Good luck getting MySQL to convert that to an integer.

Comment: Ok, Do you have `,`'s in your column data? if yes that could be a issue.

Comment: @KalaikumarThangasamy yes I do.  Basically, if I search for items that cost between 5,000 to 10,000, I should get search results that have that price range so there's commas.  My current datatype is VARCHAR (255).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You must be the most helpful guy on the web.....

Comment: @Thomas: Look at my profile — I have helped 14.3 _million_ people. How many have you helped? Tonight I have spent my own free time trying to get you to help us help you. If you're not interested in that, not my problem. Good luck. Refund's in the post.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit LOL You look like a pompous dude who just responds to people and repeats the same stuff over again.  Don't matter how many people you replied but how good the support is that you provided.  I help people too.....just not in coding.

Comment: @Thomas - Your question is lacking in details, and your attitude is lacking in respect.